# Understanding Heap Index in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, heap

On Postgresql 12, given:

```
postgres=# \d bip
                Table "public.bip"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 a      | integer |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "foo_idx_a" hash (a)
```

I then ran a `explain select ...`:

```
postgres=# explain select * from bip where a = 42;
                               QUERY PLAN                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on bip  (cost=4.10..14.80 rows=13 width=4)
   Recheck Cond: (a = 42)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_idx_a  (cost=0.00..4.10 rows=13 width=0)
         Index Cond: (a = 42)
(4 rows)
```

What is the meaning of the `Recheck Cond: (a = 42)` in the `EXPLAIN` output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959814/what-does-recheck-cond-in-explain-result-mean and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154351